# Error executing a test with jest in React with Vite project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I have a problem when i try to execute the test in my project, i spend a while searching how can i fix it but i don't find an answer.

The command that i using for execute the test is:

`package.json`

```json
"test": "jest --watchAll --detectOpenHandles"
```

and what i see in the console is the next error:

```bash
  ● Test suite failed to run                                      
                                                                  
    Jest encountered an unexpected token                          
                                                                  
    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code 
or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Je
st is not configured to support such syntax.                      
                                                                  
    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to tran
sform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration. 
                                                                  
    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.  
                                                                  
    Here's what you can do:                                       
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://je
stjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.             
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/
docs/getting-started#using-typescript                             
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you 
can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.    
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" o
ption in your config.                                             
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary
 assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config 
option.                                                           
                                                                  
    You'll find more details and examples of these config options 
in the docs:                                                      
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration                          
    For information about custom transformations, see:            
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation                    
                                                                  
    Details:                                                      
                                                                  
    <root>\node_modules\.
pnpm\query-string@8.1.0\node_modules\query-string\index.js:1      
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirna
me,__filename,jest){import * as queryString from './base.js';     
                    ^^^^^^                                        
                                                                  
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module     
                                                                  
      2 | import { HeroCard } from '../components';               
      3 |         
    > 4 | import queryString from 'query-string';                 
        | ^                                                       
      5 | import { getHeroesByName } from '../helpers';           
      6 |                                                         
      7 | export const SearchPage = () => {                       
                                                                  
      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/.pnpm/jest-run
time@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)     
      at Object.require (src/heroes/pages/SearchPage.jsx:4:1)     
      at Object.require (src/heroes/pages/index.js:4:1)           
      at Object.require (src/heroes/index.js:1:1)                 
      at Object.require (src/router/AppRouter.jsx:4:1)            
      at Object.require (tests/router/AppRouter.test.jsx:4:1)
```

Finally, if i comment the line:

```js
import queryString from 'query-string';
```

My test pass successfully but i need this importation.

In the console says that i can fix it, searching in the [jestjs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) web for can configure it well, but i don't understand to much, can anyone help me?

Comment: Use a version of `query-string` that publishes commonjs then. That or run jest as esm. Try `npm i query-string@7.1.3`.